# Dynamic resource support in WSO2 IS for Access Control

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am new to WSO2 IS and evaluating it for our Access Management(AM) use cases. I have a couple of questions if someone can please help in answering them:

1. Does WSO2 IS support dynamic resources ? For eg. lets say I want to do AM of a File System, I want to create XACML access control policies for each file/folder path. I want to avoid creating a resource for each File as files can be created dynamically in FS by other services/scripts/programs. However, I should be able to define access policies on files without a need for creating each file as a resource. Is that feasible with WSO2 IS and how can I do this ?
2. Does WSO2 IS act as a LDAP server for applications? For instance, I have a use case where I want to authenticate users with some external IdP such as Facebook. I know I can use WSO2 IS Federated Authenticator here. However, some of my services work only with LDAP protocol. So is it possible to integrate external IdP using OAuth2/SAML/OIDC protocol but provide LDAP query support for services ?
3. Another feature I am looking for is mechanism to retrieve token of external IdP. For instance in Azure Cloud, I can use WSO2 IS and Federated Authenticator to do authentication with Azure AD. However, if I want to access other cloud services such as ADLS from my service, I will need Azure AD token as well. Is there some API using which I can fetch token of external IdP.
4. One last thing. I couldn't find any documentation on ability to export XACML policies defined in WSO2 IS. I see there is documentation on import (https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS450/Importing+an+XACML+Policy). Can someone please provide information on how to export policies with WSO2 IS ?

Answer (score 0):

1) You can create XACML policies for resources which are not available/which you wish to restrict. Furthermore, you also can use a wild card resource location as well in the xacml policy. Policies can not be dynamically updated.

2) We are not a LDAP server, but we can plug an LDAP. Then all the add user, add group services happen on top of this LDAP. So if you connect to a Federted IDP using SAML, you can login with a federated user and provision that user details to this LDAP. Then you can use this user details to other functionalities of IS and your application.

3) We have no OOTB  APIs to fetch federatedIDPs tokens. As Identity server, we take the access token and idetoken from the federated IDP and get the userdetails and provision that user to the IS. By customizing the Federated authenticators we can achieve that.

4) You can use our EntitlementAdminService to achieve that task from below APIs https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Entitlement+with+APIs#EntitlementwithAPIs-getPolicy()

We have recently released IS 5.8.0 which is much improved and has better performance.